# Case statement don't work

Tags: ruby, if-statement, case

I'm learning Ruby from "Programming Ruby, The Pragmatic Programmers(2nd, 2005)" and I'm stuck in the Case statement chapter.
So i copy-paste some code in my version from book:

```
def kind
  puts "Type year and I'll tell you genre: "
  ask = gets.chomp

  kind = case ask
  when 1850..1889 then "Blues"
  when 1890..1909 then "Ragtime"
  when 1910..1929 then "New Orleans Jazz"
  when 1930..1939 then "Swing"
  when 1940..1950 then "Bebop"
  else "Jazz"
end


puts "You typed year #{ask}. Genre of music in that period is 
       #{kind}."
end

kind
```

Hence, whatever year I'm put, output is "Jazz"...What am I working incorrectly?

Comment: `ask = gets.chomp.to_i` or `case ask.to_i`.

Comment: That's why I commented it and didn't answer it. I don't often use case statements. I tried it in IRB afterward and deleted my comment.

Comment: @Martin np, I have already provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

`gets.chomp` returns a string, and you are comparing that with integers.

You can inspect `ask` after you assigned it:

```
ask = gets.chomp
p ask
```

When you run the script and enter a number (e.g. 1940), you should see  `"1940"` printed in the terminal. The quotes around the number show you that the variable holds a string, not a number. (FYI don't use `puts` here, since it won't show the quotes.)

As mudasobwa wrote in his comment, the way to fix this is to cast the input to a number before you compare it:

```
ask = gets.chomp.to_i
```

If you add `p ask` again, you should now see that only the number is printed to the terminal, without any `"` surrounding it. This shows you that the variable holds an integer.